# Click to apply style to an element whilst removing from others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm creating a simple calculator in React (Gatsby) and I wanted to give a background color to whatever operation button I click whilst removing all styles from the other buttons previously clicked.

I understand I could assign a state to each button then write a conditional to remove their styling but that sounds unwieldy. I'd like to know if there's a more organic and scalable way to accomplish that.

Thanks in advance for your cooperation.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default () => {
  const [ input1, setInput1 ] = useState();
  const [ input2, setInput2 ] = useState();
  const [ operation, setOperation ] = useState("add");
  const [ bg, setBg] = useState("");

  const handleInput1 = (event) => {
    const newInput = event.target.value;

    setInput1(prevResult => newInput);
  };

  const handleInput2 = (event) => {
    const newInput = event.target.value;

    setInput2(prevResult => newInput);
  };

  const operationSwitch = () => {
    switch (operation) {
      case "add":
        return parseInt(input1) + parseInt(input2);
        break;
      case "subtract":
        return parseInt(input1) - parseInt(input2);
        break;
      case "multiply":
        return parseInt(input1) * parseInt(input2);
        break;
      case "divide":
        return parseInt(input1) / parseInt(input2);
        break;
    }
  };

  const handleBackground = (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor === "red" ? event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "" : event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  };

  const buttonOperation = {
    add: (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setOperation(newOperation => newOperation = "add");
      handleBackground(event);
    },
    subtract: (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setOperation(newOperation => newOperation = "subtract");
      handleBackground(event);
    },
    multiply: (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setOperation(newOperation => newOperation = "multiply");
      handleBackground(event);
    },
    divide: (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setOperation(newOperation => newOperation = "divide");
      handleBackground(event);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div id="main-grid">
      <main>
        <div id="main-content">
          <input id="input1" type="number" name="input1" value={input1} onChange={handleInput1} />
          <div id="opBtns">
            <button id="add" onClick={buttonOperation.add}>+</button>
            <button id="subtract" onClick={buttonOperation.subtract}>-</button>
            <button id="multiply" onClick={buttonOperation.multiply}>*</button>
            <button id="divide" onClick={buttonOperation.divide}>/</button>
          </div>
          <input id="input2" type="number" name="input2" value={input2} onChange={handleInput2} />
          <h1>=</h1>
          <input id="result" type="number" name="result" value={operationSwitch()}  />
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer>
        Footer
      </footer>
    </div>
  );  
};
```

```css
/* CSS Reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Global CSS */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #114357;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #98c064, #576829);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #98c064, #576829); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

#main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 10vh) 10vh;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer";
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(1fr, 2fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    ". . . . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . main-content main-content . . . . ."
    ". . . . . main-content main-content . . . . ."
    ". . . . . main-content main-content . . . . ."
    ". . . . . main-content main-content . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . . . . . .";
}

#main-content {
  /* background-color: royalblue; */
  grid-area: main-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#input1 {
  grid-area: input1;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

#opBtns {
  grid-area: opBtns;
}

#add {
  grid-area: add;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

#subtract {
  grid-area: subtract;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

#multiply {
  grid-area: multiply;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

#divide {
  grid-area: divide;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

#input2 {
  grid-area: input2;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#result {
  grid-area: result;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgb(128, 19, 0);
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

I wasn't able to set up a Gatsby app in a code snippet so I just provided the JavaScript and CSS. If you need, here's the [Github Repository](https://github.com/RenanMDP/calculator-gatsby) and the [deployed site in production](https://serene-montalcini-a8cd22.netlify.app/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is add a conditional attribute that only shows up on the selected button.

```
<div id="opBtns">
    <button id="add" onClick={buttonOperation.add} data-selected={operation === "add"}>+</button>
    <button id="subtract" onClick={buttonOperation.subtract} data-selected={operation === "subtract"}>-</button>
    <button id="multiply" onClick={buttonOperation.multiply} data-selected={operation === "multiply"}>*</button>
    <button id="divide" onClick={buttonOperation.divide} data-selected={operation === "divide"}>/</button>
</div>
```

Then you could target that button with css

```css
button[data-selected] {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but the condition doesn't work, it just leave all the buttons red. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Martineli try `button[data-selected="true"]`

Comment: That works too. And it's even more compact. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a dynamic class with `useState` hook (like you do with the background)?

```
  const [ classNames, setClassNames ] = useState('');
```

Then in your `switch` you can customize whatever you like, for example:

```
  const buttonOperation = {
    add: (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setOperation(newOperation => newOperation = "add");
      handleBackground(event);
      setClassNames('add');
    },
    subtract: (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setOperation(newOperation => newOperation = "subtract");
      handleBackground(event);
      setClassNames('subtract');
    },
    multiply: (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setOperation(newOperation => newOperation = "multiply");
      handleBackground(event);
      setClassNames('multiply');

    },
    divide: (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setOperation(newOperation => newOperation = "divide");
      handleBackground(event);
      setClassNames('divide');
    }
  };
```

Finally in your `return()`:

```
  <div id="opBtns" className={classNames}>
```

In your CSS/Sass you can custom the background or whatever property you like.

Comment: That's much better than to create a state for each button. Thanks a lot.